Parse Visual Studio Test Explorer playlist (Parse XML)
I am trying to find a better way to parse a saved playlist from Visual Studio. Which is xml file. This is an example of a saved playlist:
<Playlist Version="2.0">
  <Rule Name="Includes" Match="Any">
    <Rule Match="All">
      <Property Name="Solution" />
      <Rule Match="Any">
        <Rule Match="All">
          <Property Name="Project" Value="MyProject" />
          <Rule Match="Any">
            <Rule Match="All">
              <Property Name="Namespace" Value="MyProject" />
              <Rule Match="Any">
                <Rule Match="All">
                  <Property Name="Class" Value="TestArc" />
                  <Rule Match="Any">
                    <Rule Match="All">
                      <Property Name="TestWithNormalizedFullyQualifiedName" Value="MyProject.TestArc.Insert_Arc" />
                      <Rule Match="Any">
                        <Property Name="DisplayName" Value="Insert_Arc" />
                      </Rule>
                    </Rule>
                    <Rule Match="All">
                      <Property Name="TestWithNormalizedFullyQualifiedName" Value="MyProject.TestArc.Insert_Arc_For_Construction" />
                      <Rule Match="Any">
                        <Property Name="DisplayName" Value="Insert_Arc_For_Construction(True)" />
                        <Property Name="DisplayName" Value="Insert_Arc_For_Construction(False)" />
                      </Rule>
                    </Rule>
                  </Rule>
                </Rule>
              </Rule>
            </Rule>
          </Rule>
        </Rule>
      </Rule>
    </Rule>
  </Rule>
</Playlist>

What I am after are the values of the properties with the name DisplayName.
By using the example xml, the result I am after are three rows consisting of:

Insert_Arc
Insert_Arc_For_Construction(True)
Insert_Arc_For_Construction(False)

The below c# code solves that, but I feel it is not the "correct", or best way to do it and would appreciate some pointers and better solutions
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"vs-3-tests.playlist");

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Property");

int counter = 0;

foreach (XmlElement elem in nodeList)
{
    if (elem.HasAttributes)
    {
        if (elem.Attributes[0].Value == "DisplayName")
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine($"{counter} - {elem.Attributes[1].Value}");
        }
    }
}


You could avoid the if inside your loop by passing the following XML path to SelectNodes(): "//Property[@Name='DisplayName']".

And if you use "//Property[@Name='DisplayName']/@Value" you will get a list of XmlAttributes instead of XmlElements. This allows you to get an IEnumerable<string> of the desired values like so: .SelectNodes("//Property[@Name='DisplayName']/@Value").Cast<XmlAttribute>().Select(x => x.Value)

Using Xml Linq :
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<string> values = doc.Descendants("Property")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == "DisplayName")
                .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Value"))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}

